# Passing Multi Value Paramter in stored proc

Tags: stored-procedures

```
Firstname             emp_Fullname
--------------------------------------
chetan                Patel, Chetan
mike                  Shah, Mike                  
ronie                 Desai, Ronie


create proc stored_procedure
    @firstnamer varchar(max)
    @fullname varchar(max)
as
begin
     select ......
     from....
     where Firstname in (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@firstname,','))
     --and emp_Fullname in (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@fullname,','))
```

I want result for below statement

```
exec stored_procedure 'chetan,ronie', 'Patel, Chetan,Shah, Mike'
```

How can I pass more than 2 `emp_fullname` in parameter in given stored procedure? Below is my function `dbo.FnSplit` that worked for multi value `Firstname` parameter but not working multi value `fullname` parameter.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FnSplit]
(
@List nvarchar(2000),
@SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table (Id int identity(1,1), Value nvarchar(100))
AS
BEGIN
     WHILE(Charindex(@SplitOn, @List) > 0)
     BEGIN
           INSERT INTO @RtnValue (value)
               SELECT 
                   VALUE = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List, 1, Charindex(@SplitOn, @List) - 1)))

           SET @List = SUBSTRING(@List, Charindex(@SplitOn, @List) + len(@SplitOn), len(@List))
     END

     INSERT INTO @RtnValue (Value)
        SELECT 
            VALUE = ltrim(rtrim(@List))
     RETURN
END
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Hey I just improved the format try again now and see if you can help me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstname in (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@firstname,'|'))
and emp_Fullname in (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@fullname,'|'))

and I figured that still in SSRS double click on dataset click parmater instead of default value choose expression and set it to "join(@firstname.value,"|")" and samething for other "join(@fullname.value,"|")" and now run it. Multi valye parameter should work find by doing above procedure.
Thanks to my self lol:) it took me 3 days to figured, thought you guys can use it!